# Reference initialization in C++ when private unique_ptr is involved in class definition

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

How the compile error below can be explained?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
    unique_ptr<vector<short>> v;
public:
    A(){
        v = unique_ptr<vector<short>>(new vector<short>());
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }
    A(const A& a) : A(){
        cout << "A(const A& a)" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    A a1; // prints A()
    A a2 = a1; // prints A() then A(const A& a)
    A& a3 = a1; // prints nothing
    a3 = a1; // compile time error: use of deleted function ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)

    return 0;
}
```

Actually, why `A& a3 = a1` is ok and `a3 = a1`is not? Also, which overloaded version of the operator= is being used and how could it be properly implemented to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: `A& a3 = a;` initializes a reference. No assignments involved.+

Comment: "...the compile error below.." - you forgot to include the *exact* reported error text in your question, which you should *always* do when asking why an error is happening, or what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the line

```
a3 = a1;
```

you are invoking a deleted `operator=` (remember that `unique_ptr` is non-copyable). g++ spits out the error for you:

> > error: use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)'

Whereas in the line

```
A& a3 = a1;
```

there is no copy made, you only initialize a reference.

You may want to move your pointer, like

```
a3 = std::move(a1);
```

Unfortunately, it won't work, since you explicitly declared a copy constructor, and this prevents the compiler from generating the default move constructor and assignment operator. Solution: declare the move assignment operator and move constructors as `=default;`,

```
A& operator=(A&&) = default;
A(A&&) = default;
```

and the line `a3 = std::move(a1)` above will work.

Comment: So `operator=` is not called when `A& a3 = a1; `  is performed?

Comment: No, not at all. Even in the non-reference case, it is not the assignment operator that's being called, but the copy constructor (remember that you are just constructing the object). But in your case, you're not constructing anything, you are just initializing a reference to an already constructed object, there is no creation of a new object/assignment involved here.

Comment: I would like to see the magic performed by these `default` operations. Is there a way by how I can see the code corresponding to these default operations?

Comment: you should ask a C++ committee member :) Roughly they invoke the move of all movable types your class defines. If a class contain a non-movable type (for example, a type where you delete the move constructor), then these functions are not generated. You can probably see the code if you disassemble some small program.

Comment: Ok @vsoftco, I think I'll study more deeply how these move operations work behind the covers, thanks for the advice.